# How do i get middle name from a textbox?

Tags: c#

So i have a textbox in which the user enters his/her fullname, if the user enters a name like let say "John William Nathan Smith" how do i get only "Nathan Smith". It can be "John William Nathan" and i need "William" in this case. how do i retrieve that?
i did an array named `name` like so:

```
       string fullname = txtFull.Text;
       string[] name = fullname.Split(null);

       txtFirst.Text = name.First();
       txtLast.Text = name.Last();
       txtMid.Text = name[1] + " " + name[(name.Length - 2)];        //textbox to output
```

Comment: For "John William Nathan Smith" you want "William Nathan" right?

Comment: You need to add a test for the presence of at least two elements in the _name_ array

Comment: Grab all the words from your split operation except the first and last word and string.join them together. It should also be easy for you to figure out when the user did not enter a middle-name (like only giving "John Smith" or just "Smith" as full name, for example).

Comment: @Sweeper yes  and it can be 3names or 5names as well

Comment: Please read https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/

Comment: @Steve well i added a test for atleast 3 elements because of the middle name, contains no numbers, can't start with a space and has no punctuations but i cant figure out how to get the middle name

Comment: I think you can't solve this unless you can solve the problem of identifying the "last name" first. And unless you simply don't allow people like van Gogh or da Silva or von Neumann to use your system, that is a challenge in its own right. If you want to know different parts of people's names, ask for them explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumption: the different parts of people's names are always separated by one space, and the middle name is defined as everything between the first and last space.

(note that this assumption is not true all the time, people can have all kinds of names)

You can call `Skip` and then `Take` and then join them together:

```
string[] name = fullname.Split(' ');
string middleName = string.Join(" ", name.Skip(1).Take(name.Length - 2));
```